# How to read file again and again in C?

Tags: c, io

I am reading a txt file and send the lines to another process via pipe and I delete the txt and open it again. But When I change the lines in txt the process continuous to run but it doesn't read the lines again. How can I solve that?

```
FILE *fp;
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;

while (1) {
    fp = fopen("data", "r");

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        write(4, line, strlen(line));
    }

    if (line != NULL) {
        remove("data");
        fp = fopen("data" ,"a");
    }

    rewind(fp);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you're trying to do? it seems like a simple loop would suffice to reopen the closed file.

Comment: Of course. I've edited the post.

Comment: `remove("data")` deletes the file, so opening in append mode in the next line makes no sense. Furthermore, you should `fclose(fp)` after you're done with it. And `write(4,` is just asking for trouble. The `pipe` function gives you a proper file descriptor to use with `write`.

Comment: After you `remove` the file what do you expect to get in the file after reopening it? Why would you expect to be able to read anything from it after deleting the file?

Comment: @kaylum I have to delete the file and recreate it after the program reads and sends all the lines via pipe. When I recreate the file I put new numbers in new txt file but the program doesn't read the new file's values.

Comment: Which part of the code are you claiming would "read the new file's values"? You `fopen` the same file that you have just deleted.

Comment: You're opening `'data'` twice in your `while(1)` loop after you remove the file. You do `fp = fopen("data", "a");`, then `rewind(fp)` then followed by `fp = fopen("data", "r")`. Is that your intention?

Comment: @kaylum sir, yes I've deleted the file but fp("data", "a") opens new file with the same name and I thought the infinite while loop reads the new file with the same name again and again.

Comment: Since you're doing multiple opens on the file without closing it, there will be remaining file descriptors open when you attempt to remove it. According to the `remove` manual page: *If the name was the last link to a file, but any processes still have the file open, the file will remain in existence until the last file descriptor referring to it is closed.*

Comment: You are leaking file descriptor (file streams).  If you remove the file and try to open it again on the next line, the chances are high that the open will fail.  You also don't check the `fopen()` at the top of the loop.  You always need to check `fopen()` results.  You should close the file at the end of the loop, arguably before removing it.  You don't need to reopen at the bottom of the loop; the open at the top of the loop is all you need (and a matching `fclose()`).  And checking that `fopen()` worked.  And sleeping if it didn't — probably.

Comment: Also you have an infinite loop. `while(1)` will never exit unless there is a `break;` somewhere within the loop. Generally this is bad programming, and you should have an exit flag set instead, that is compared to a value. Do this instead `while(someFlag = someValue)` and then when you're ready to break out of your loop, set `someFlag` to a different value and let the loop exit naturally.

Comment: @JoelTrauger I think it's the intention of this program: to run endlessly.